# Pip is not recognized, despite all references existing in PATH Environment Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

I've been using Python for a bit, and have been running into some trouble using Pip. I have Python 3.6 installed on Windows 10, and have been able to get by on installing packages by installing the source file, then unpacking and using

```
python setup.py install
```

This works fine, however I've run into some issues when trying to install lxml, and would really like to be able to use Pip. I've added everything to my path variable since the very beginning, and have the output of

```
echo %PATH%
```

as

```
C:\Python36\;C:\Python36\Scripts\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin;C:\Users\[name]\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Python36\;C:\Python36\Scripts
```

I'm lost on this problem, because despite C:\Python36\Scripts\ existing, when I run

```
pip install <package name>
```

I receive

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try Closing and opening the command window again , if you have recently set the path

Answer (score 0):

seems like your PATH is set to C:\Python36\Scripts. if it is from python 3.6.2 or above try to set the PATH to C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts instead

`setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files(x86)\Python36-32\Scripts"`
sometimes you would have to do set the environmental variable manually (under system properties).

make sure you run `pip` from that directory, and remember to reopen cmd after you set the path.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PATH and set it again.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python36\Scripts
```

or

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python36\Scripts"
```

to set it permanently.

Also even after that if you get `pip` not recognizable. Try

```
pip.exe install -your_package-
```

instead of

```
pip install -your_package-
```

or maybe try,

```
python -m pip install [packagename]
```

If all fails try,

```
C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install  [package].whl
```

Try this after `cd` -ing to the directory where your `[package].whl` is located.

Hope this works.